# ¿Como no enviar un parámetro a una función?

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente funcion que recibe ciertos parametros

```
function realizarAsignacionTraslado(NumeroDocumento, Monto, Tipo_Prestamo, NumeroPrestamo, Cod_Fiador){
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: `https://URL/metodo?NumeroDocumento=${NumeroDocumento}&Monto=${Monto}&Tipo_Prestamo=${Tipo_Prestamo}&NumeroPrestamo=${NumeroPrestamo}&Cod_Fiador=${Cod_Fiador}`,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                });
        })
    }
```

dichos parametros `NumeroDocumento, Monto, Tipo_Prestamo, NumeroPrestamo, Cod_Fiador` son enviados de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#btn-realizar-pago').on('click', function(e){
        console.log("REALIZANDO EL PAGO");
        if (JSON.stringify(prestamo_seleccionado)=='{}') {
                console.log('vacio');
            $.each(asignacion_credito, function(index, value){
                console.log(value);
                if (value.NumeroPrestamo === ""){
                    realizarAsignacionTraslado(value.NumeroDocumento, parseFloat(value.Monto), value.Tipo_Prestamo,"",value.Cod_fiador);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("Existe prestamo selecionado: ");
            console.log(prestamo_seleccionado);
        }
        $('.cantidad').val("");
        asignacion_credito = [];
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

El problema que tengo es que en algun caso el parametro `NumeroPrestamo` no lo debo enviar, entonces para el caso de no enviar el parametro tampoco debe ir en la url, de tal forma que la URL quede de la siguiente manera`https://URL/metodo?NumeroDocumento=${NumeroDocumento}&Monto=${Monto}&Tipo_Prestamo=${Tipo_Prestamo}&Cod_Fiador=${Cod_Fiador}` como veran ya no contiene `&NumeroPrestamo=${NumeroPrestamo}`

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual es la condición que define en que caso debes o no enviar el parámetro "NumeroPrestamo"? Tengo otra duda, porque utlizas parámetros GET con un método POST?

Comment: la condicion es donde se encuentra este  if (value.NumeroPrestamo === ""), en realizadad el uso del metodo POST es porque asi tiene el funcionamiento esa api, segun entiendo es porque se envia el token de autorizacion. Perdon eso no lo tengo claro, unicamente utilizo esos metodos para mandar parametros.

Comment: Me refiero a cual es el caso que determina cuando debe enviarse o no, es decir, cuando existe un numero previo, o cuando no existe. Cuando el usuario ya pagó o cuando no ha pagado... en tu algoritmo, en que caso es cuando requieres no enviar este parámetro? Es para comprender mejor tu script, le falta un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Ah ok perdon, es que en algunos casos el usuario podra utilizar un prestamo o su propio dinero, entonces ese metodo me sirve para ambos, pero cuando el usuario haya seleccionado un prestamo en ese momento si existira valor para el parametro NumeroPrestamo, caso contrario no existe valor para ese parametro por lo tanto no es necesario que vaya en la URL.

Comment: Ya intentaste tener una función para cuando se trata de un préstamo y existe ese valor y crear otra función para cuando no hay préstamo y ese valor no existe. De modo que tengas un condicional que determine que función usar según sea el caso... o que razón hay para que sea la misma función la que resuelva ambos casos?

Comment: Pues creo que de ultimo momento realizare de esa forma, lo que sucede es que no se quiere consumir recurso para hacer uso de otra función, ya que esto es para una aplicación hibrida.

Comment: Ok. bueno, tal vez otra opción podría ser que coloques este parámetro que podría ir vacío o simplemente no existir al final en el orden de como los recibes en la función (me parece que si el último valor no se recibe al menos no se corta el flujo) y dentro de la función pones el condicional que indique que si se recibe ese valor y no está vacío te envíe la URL con todos los valores, en caso contrario que sólo envíe los valores disponibles. No se si me di a entender bien.

Comment: Si pudieras escribir tu respuesta con código, te agradecería mucho así probar y confirmar tu respuesta como la correcta a mi problema. De antemano muchas gracias por tu tiempo.